# Regex with Exclusion in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a regex `.*(?<=code=)(.*?)(;|$).*` which allows me pull specific pattern ("code") out of a list. But whenever the intended pattern ("code") is not present in a particular row, the entire row shows up in the result.

Dateset:

```
rev=63;code=ATL;qty=1;zip=45987
rev=10.60|34;qty=1|2;zip=12686|12694;code=NY
rev=12;qty=7;zip=71565
rev=1.6|4;qty=4|2;zip=4548|464;code=KT
rev=8;qty=1;zip=74268
rev=3|24|8;qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254
```

Current Output (With substitution *\1*):

```
ATL
NY
rev=12;qty=7;zip=71565
KT
rev=8;qty=1;zip=74268
TPA
```

Intended Output:

```
ATL
NY

KT

TPA
```

Comment: Could you describe what you base on to extract values ie how would you explain what you intend to do without knowledge of your RegEx?

Comment: try this [`(?:.*(?<=code=)(.*?)(;|$).*)|.*`](https://regex101.com/r/2iFJEI/1/), here idea is match the otherwise string completely and do not capture that, since your current regex only matches the lines with `code` so your replace doesn't affect those line which doesn't matches

Comment: @CodeManiac Thanks! It worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract the data using `stringr::str_extract`:

```
x <- c("rev=63;code=ATL;qty=1;zip=45987","rev=10.60|34;qty=1|2;zip=12686|12694;code=NY","rev=12;qty=7;zip=71565","rev=1.6|4;qty=4|2;zip=4548|464;code=KT","rev=8;qty=1;zip=74268","rev=3|24|8;qty=1|6|3;code=TPA;zip=33684|36842|30254")
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=\\bcode=)[^;]+")
# => [1] "ATL" "NY"  NA    "KT"  NA    "TPA"
```

If you do not want `NA` and want empty items use

```
matches <- str_extract(x, "(?<=\\bcode=)[^;]+")
matches[is.na(matches)] <- ""
matches
## => [1] "ATL" "NY"  ""    "KT"  ""    "TPA"
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\bcode=)` - a [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) matching a location immediately preceded with a whole word `code` and a `=`
- `[^;]+` - a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches and consumes (i.e. adds to to the output and moves the regex index) 1 or more chars other than `;`.